# How to set Terminal in right starting position

Tags: linux, archlinux, arch

I started using Garuda Linux and wanted to customize my Starting Desktop.
I want my terminal to start in the center of my desktop, but its launching in top left corner. How can i center my terminal in the middle of the screen?

[image: How it starts]

[image: How i want it to start]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your display system. But if you use X11 you should be able to adapt this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48989).